# Adding a JOIN to SQL query gives different result, its not an accidental CROSS JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image: This is the tables relationship]...

Trying to learn SQL and the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, w.channel, COUNT(*) use_of_channel
FROM accounts a
JOIN web_events w
ON a.id = w.account_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, w.channel
HAVING COUNT(*) > 6 AND w.channel = 'facebook'
ORDER BY use_of_channel;
```

returns 46 results [(first query results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh6SW.png), JUST ADDING A JOIN of an unrelated table returns 220 results.
Its **not** a CROSS JOIN since it seems properly formatted, just added down here at line 5 a JOIN with "orders" table

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, w.channel, COUNT(*) use_of_channel
FROM accounts a
JOIN web_events w
ON a.id = w.account_id
JOIN orders o
ON o.account_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, w.channel
HAVING COUNT(*) > 6 AND w.channel = 'facebook'
ORDER BY use_of_channel;
```

[image: (second query results)]

...but why would another table compromise the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* a cross join.  That is, each account has multiple events.  And each account has multiple orders.  So *within each account* you are getting a Cartesian product.

A quick way to fix this is to use `count(distinct)` on a primary key:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, w.channel,
       COUNT(w.id) as use_of_channel
```

Comment: You do have a point, I though that using JOIN-ON and GROUP BY would avoid me the CROSS JOIN situation, yet it seems like it still returns doubles of "account" row for each "order" linked to it, and therefore more "channel" elements.
Following your advise I placed this: ```HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.id) > 6 AND w.channel = 'facebook'``` in the query and the results now match. Thank you!